# Attempted to call function "ldap_connect" from namespace "App\Bundle\Controller".

Tags: php, symfony, ldap

I can't use the `ldap_connect` function but I checked in php.ini and it's in.

I didn't find this error on Internet. Everyone is having "Call to undefined function" but I got "Attempted" and can't figure why.

I checked with `function_exists('ldap_connect')` and it was false.

I use Symfony2, apache and PHP 5.5.9.

I call the function from my controller and I get the parameters from parameters.yml :

```
$ldap_user = $this->container->getParameter('ldap_user');
$ldap_pass= $this->container->getParameter('ldap_pass');
$ldap_co = ldap_connect($this->container->getParameter('ldap_address'));
```

If someone could help me that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check `phpinfo`? Is there `ldap` on the list of extensions?

Comment: please check with phpinfo() for installed extensions. Maybe you have different setup for different environments (i.e. CGI and CLI)

Comment: The only `ldap` I found is in the CREDITS section :/ So what do I need to do ? I also checked with `php -m` and it's not in the list

Comment: try `$ldap_co = \ldap_connect($this->container->getParameter('ldap_address'));`

Comment: Well, got that instead : `Attempted to call function "ldap_connect" from the global namespace. `

Comment: did you install php5-ldap via "apt-get install php5-ldap"?

Comment: Yes, all that part is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I find the answer. It was an apache2 issue.

I went in `/etc/apache2/mods-available` to check if `ldap.conf` and `ldap.load` were in, and they were. Then I checked in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` in which they were not. And that's the problem.

So I ran the following command : `sudo a2enmod ldap` in order to activate the ldap module for apache2. Then `sudo service apache2 reload` and in the instant I saw it enabled in `phpinfo()`.

Maybe that's not the correct way to do it, if anyone have a better answer I'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `ldap` extension to php. To do that (paths are from Ubuntu) add symbolic link `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Sep 23  2014 20-ldap.ini -> ../../mods-available/ldap.ini
```

(similar to `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d` if you want to have this available in `cli`)

Check [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php) for more info

Comment: Ok I figured. But it's in both folders... 20-ldap.ini I mean

Comment: @Von_Kavalier What OS, web server and php processing module do you use? If you use Ubuntu as Tomasz suggested you need make symbolic link to proper environment, for instance if you use php-fpm you need make link from `/etc/php5/mods-available/ldap.ini` to folder `/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/` Also don't forget to restart web server (if PHP is used as web-server module) or cgi/fpm service

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu, using Apache, and cli if I'm right. The symlink is already done.. That's why I don't understand why the function is not called